# ETCD fails to start, running CoreOS on AWS,EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, coreos, etcd

I use ami-05ffb06f, t2.micro EC2 instance.

I use cloud-config to start etcd, but it fails to start

```
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connection refused
error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connection refused
```

I tried to manually start it

```
cd /bin  
./etcd
```

It says

```
[etcd] Jan 18 09:49:46.555 WARNING   | Using the directory ip-172-31-1-86.ec2.internal.etcd as the etcd curation directory because a directory was not specified.
[etcd] Jan 18 09:49:46.555 CRITICAL  | Unable to create path: mkdir ip-172-31-1-86.ec2.internal.etcd: read-only file system
```

Now if I set data-dir parameter to home it works fine

```
./etcd -data-dir=~/
```

Why can't it create the folder in its default location?

Answer (score 1):

This generally means nothing is listening or a firewall is blocking see the link below.

> [Error: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connection refused error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connection refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

This

> CRITICAL | Unable to create path: mkdir ip-172-31-1-86.ec2.internal.etcd: read-only file system

Suggests that the filesystem you are trying to write to is read only, I guess you may get this message if the user you are trying to run the startup as doesn't have suitable privilege.

There are [some ideas here](https://serverfault.com/questions/193971/determine-if-filesystem-or-partition-is-mounted-ro-or-rw-via-bash-script) on how to determine if the filesystem is readonly. If it's not then ensure that teh user has suitable privileges etc.