# Using SNMP for detecting filesystem anomalies (read-only, etc.)

Tags: filesystems, mount, snmp

Usually when there is a problem, the filesystem mounts itself read-only:

```
[449551.919049] EXT3-fs (dm-2): error: ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
[449551.919056] EXT3-fs (dm-2): error: remounting filesystem read-only
```

Now I tried to catch that using monitoring via SNMP that we have in place anyway, but it didn't:

```
# snmpwalk -c public -v 2c localhost HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrFSTable
SNMP table: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrFSTable

...
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrFSAccess.11 = INTEGER: readWrite(1)
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrFSAccess.12 = INTEGER: readWrite(1) ***
```

It seems to show the configured, not the current state.

Is there any other way to catch this, preferably using SNMP, without resorting to actually having to write a file and check the outcome?

BTW

- OS: SLES11-SP3
- Kernel 3.0.101
- net-snmp-5.4.2.1

Comment: Combination of extension command in snmpd.conf and recipies from here (https://serverfault.com/questions/193971/determine-if-filesystem-or-partition-is-mounted-ro-or-rw-via-bash-script) should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't you like to add this as an answer? My comment and follow-up to that answer will be why snmp doesn't do that out-of-the-box :)

Answer (score 1):

Combination of extension command in snmpd.conf and recipies from here ([serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/193971/determine-if-filesystem-or-partition-is-mounted-ro-or-rw-via-bash-script)) should do the trick.